# Replace the Quotations in Notepad++.

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a Text file.

it has "" character like this

Example:

```
456 canady robert forsty "
" sample sample sample
457 vasu varun vocalar"
" kiran rajesh
457 vasu varun vocalar"" kiran rajesh
457 vasu varun vocalar"" kiran rajesh
```

Can I replace those two quotation marks by using "**Notepad++ find and Replace**" option ?

Because of this Quotation mark details going into next line...

SO i just want to replace those two quotes with some blank space they look normal.

Its an 13MB file 100389 lines...
I have seen the Find option with regular expression in Notepad++ but i am not good at Regular expression.

write a line for us.

Note : I just want to replace those Quotation marks which are coming in the shown pattern.

Comment: *write a line for us*?!

Comment: He wants to replace "" with nothing and "\r\n" with just \r\n.  I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can always escape special characters with a backslash (\) in regular expressions, so you should put a \ sign in front of the special character like: "

Removing " characters and removing line breaks are two different things.
Both can be done in Notepad++ Find&Replace.

Just check the Regular expression check box, and replace **\"** to nothing and press replace all. This will replace all " characters to nothing.
If you want to replace them to a space, then replace **\"** to SPACE

For removing line breaks, replace **(\r)?\n** to nothing

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
fmarton

Answer (score 0):

Hm. In your example this is works:

Find `""` Replace `<empty>`

Find `"\r\n"` Replace `\r\n`

Both with enabled "regex" option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regular expression this should work:

Find: \"\r\n\"

Replace: ""

Would make

```
456 canady robert forsty "
" sample sample sample
457 vasu varun vocalar"
" kiran rajesh
457 vasu varun vocalar"" kiran rajesh
457 vasu varun vocalar"" kiran rajesh
```

Look like

```
456 canady robert forsty "" sample sample sample
457 vasu varun vocalar"" kiran rajesh
457 vasu varun vocalar"" kiran rajesh
457 vasu varun vocalar"" kiran rajesh
```

Ofcourse you could also replace it with an empty string which would also remove the quotation marks.

Saying

> Because of this Quotation mark details going into next line..

is a bit inaccurate, its not the quotation marks that cause the new line, its the carriage return and linefeed characters (CRLF, \r\n) which is "invisible" characters between the quotation marks. You can make notepad++ show these special characters by pressing the [image] sign in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `"\R?"`
Replace with: `NOTHING`